# Capacitor App running only for the first time

Tags: android, plugins, capacitor, ionic-native

The first time I install my capacitor app on a device the app works correctly. But if I close my app, and open again the app don’t work anymore and get stuck on the white screen forever.The app also works fine in debug mode.

If I put debug point anywhere in the listener I get the output and even when I run the app for the first timeI get the output but from the second time if I run the app I get clank screen.

I am using TransferListner in my plugin and added plugin to capacitor app. This listener is not firing the second time and time after that.I have this problem on Android. I have tried so many solutions like adding permissions in manifest file,invalidate cache/restart, clean and rebuild..etc but still having same problem.

Can anyone suggest or help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue? I'm having same error